# Restful API thread clashing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a shopping cart API to add the item to table when the item doesn't exist, and then increase the qty column each time the item is then added:

```
var exist = _context.Carts.Any(a => a.CartID == dto.CartSesID && a.SweetID == dto.SweetID);


        if (!exist)
        {
            // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
            var cartItem = new Cart
            {
                SweetID = dto.SweetID,
                CartID = dto.CartSesID, 
                Qty = qty,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };
            _context.Carts.Add(cartItem);
        }
        else
        {
           var cartItem = _context.Carts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CartID == dto.CartSesID && a.SweetID == dto.SweetID);
            // If the item does exist in the cart, 
            // then add one to the quantity

            if(type == "plus")
            cartItem.Qty = cartItem.Qty + qty;

            if (type == "minus")
            cartItem.Qty = cartItem.Qty - qty;

            if(cartItem.Qty == 0)
            _context.Carts.Remove(cartItem);


        }
        // Save changes
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that the if (!exist) check seems to think that the item doesn't exist when the button is clicked multiple times too fast (maybe thread not finished when other has started?) resulting in the same item added on several rows:

[image]

But it should be added as the following:
[image]

Does anyone know an ideal fix?

Comment: Disable the button until the operation is finished.  You are sending the same request to the server multiple times.  Unless there is something distinct in that request, there isn't much you can do server-side to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks I have added a delay to the API post the re-enables the button, seems to work but I cant help think that solution is just masking the issue.

Comment: Adam Smith's answer will fix the server side issue - assuming that you can identify a combination of data that makes a record unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition here. When two requests follow rapidly one another, the first request may have not committed its changes to the DB before the second one queries the existence of the item in question.

You need to apply some concurrency control to resolve this. Basically there are two ways to go:

1. **Serializing** the changes made to the DB. Again, two main options:

   1. most RDBMS supports the **serializable isolation level** for transactions or
   2. you can use some **locking mechanisms**. This can take place on DB level (e.g. table locking) or application level (.NET locking constructions) depending on your application architecture.
2. You can apply a trial-and-error (or trial-and-retry-on-error to be more precise) approach aka **optimistic concurrency control**.

Obviously, serializing have a negative impact on performance (especially option 1.1)  so usually optimistic concurrency control is preferred and the other ones are for special cases.

Luckily, EF has built-in support for optimistic concurrency handling. All the details is discussed in [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

In this particular case you have an even simpler way. You need to define a compound **unique constraint** on (CartID, SweetID) fields. Doing this **guarantees that no duplicates can be inserted** into the table. You get an exception when such an attempt is detected and by catching it you can handle the situation according to your requirements. E.g. you can initiate an update (but keep in mind that even in this case you need optimistic concurrency checking to make the process absolutely fail-safe!)

**Footnote**

Disabling the button is just a masking of the problem, indeed. On server-side you cannot trust what JS does on client-side because it is completely out of your control. JS can be disabled or modified by the user easily.

**Update**

Reading through my answer again, I feel there's a conclusion I should add:

In this particular case I think the best you can do is to

- set the unique constraint as I suggested but don't care about the exception thrown when a duplicate insert is detected AND
- disable the submit button on client-side for the time of submit.

This way you ensure that no invalid data can be stored in your DB even if someone manipulates your JS code. At the same time, you don't need to overcomplicate your data persisting logic.